# list all SAS members in a ZOS libray from remote sas session

Tags: sas

On our ZOS (mainframe) we have a library called 
USER.PGM.WEEKLY 
where several sas programs(members) are located

I am trying to retrieve a list of all the member from my PCSAS with following code

```
rsubmit;

proc source indd='C009BSA.BSA.BIBHLP.SAS' select *; print;run;


endrsubmit;
signoff;
```

But it errors out with

```
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, DIRDD, INDD, MAXIOERROR, NOALIAS, 
          NODATA, NOMEM, NOPRINT, NOSUMMARY, NOTSORTED, NULL, OUTBLK, OUTDD, PAGE, PRINT, 
          SEARCH.  

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

I have tried to google around to find the solution but haven't been able to sort it out.

How ever i am able to download one member at the time by running

```
filename inpds 'USER.PGM.WEEKLY' shr;
 proc download infile =inpds(PPRINT_TO_PDF) 
 outfile='L:\Work\PPRINT_TO_PDF';
 run;
```

Comment: Isn't that what the DIRDD option on the PROC SOURCE procedure is for?  It should point to the text file you want to create with the list of members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.  You might need to use an actual physical file instead of using the TEMP filename engine on ZOS.

```
filename dirlist temp;
rsubmit;
  filename dirlist temp;
  proc source indd='C009BSA.BSA.BIBHLP.SAS' dirdd=dirlist; run;
  proc download infile=dirlist outfile=dirlist; run;
endrsubmit;
```

https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/os390/z0217440.htm

If you just want to download all of the members of the PDS then PROC DOWNLOAD can do that for you without you needing to have the list of members.

```
filename outdir '/where/I/want/to/write/';
rsubmit;
  filename indir 'C009BSA.BSA.BIBHLP.SAS';
  proc download infile=indir(*) outfile=outdir; run;
endrsubmit;
```

Comment: Thanks helped a lot :-) both your suggestions worked